# sharepoint on premise losing excel changes

Tags: excel, excel-services, sharepoint-server

SharePoint 2013 on premise is not always saving changes in Excel to the point that some colleagues are losing hours of work. Why does this keep happening?

May I add, that the drafts can be see in Office Upload Center, but even these drafts do not have the latest changes. Please guide me.

Comment: As a side note, they should use auto-save in Excel and set it to save e.g. every 15 minutes, then they won't lose hours of work.  There's no excuse for them being lazy and not using auto-save.

Comment: please explain how to set autosave up for excel in sharepoint on premise

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [MS link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/help-protect-your-files-in-case-of-a-crash-551c29b1-6a4b-4415-a3ff-a80415b92f99?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) on Excel autosave.  Your IT department might be able to enforce this centrally as a group policy.

One other thing, when users save an existing file, they can check in Sharepoint to see that the Modified Date has changed.  After saving a new file in to Sharepoint, they can also refresh the page in Sharepoint to see if the file appears - if their file does not show up in Sharepoint then the save has not been committed correctly.

[image: autosave]

Comment: Tally, is this also valid for SharePoint on Premise?

Comment: I use Sharepoint 2013 on Premise, which is the same version as yours.  So yes it is valid.  Did you look in Excel yet?

Comment: I did, and I tried it out, but I see no drafts being saved..